# PHP multiple file upload script fails upload and size set too small

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a script that I had working on my site for some time now. Recently I tried testing the file upload function and it always failed no matter the file size. Here is my PHP upload script:

```
<?php
session_start();
// IF USER NOT REMEMBERED(DID NOT CLICK REMEBER ME BUTTON) OR NO SESSION IS FOUND THEN THROW HIM OUT TO LOGIN
//SECURITY SO THAT USERS CANT ACCESS WEB URL DIRECTLY
 if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && !isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
$subject_list = $_POST['subject_list'];
$uploaddir = "/var/www/fixnode_website/content/Secure Login/Rye High/uploads/$subject_list";
$files=array();
$fdata=$_FILES['rye_file'];
if(is_array($fdata['name'])){
 for($i=0;$i<count($fdata['name']);++$i){
  $files[]=array(
   'name'     => $fdata['name'][$i],
   'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
  );
 }
}
else $files[]=$fdata;

foreach ($files as $file) {
  // uploaded location of file is $file['tmp_name']
  // original filename of file is $file['name']
  $move_file = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/".$file['name']);
}
if($move_file){
   echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded to: $subject_list folder. Please wait, your browser will refresh in 5-10 seconds!";
   header('Refresh: 10; URL=/index.php');
  } 
  else {
     echo "Upload failed";
 }
 ?>
```

Here is my HTML file upload script for reference:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
Choose Course Code:
<select name="subject_list">
<option value="None">Pick Course</option>
<option value="ACC 100">ACC 100</option>
<option value="ACC 406">ACC 406</option>
<option value="ECN 104">ECN 104</option>
<option value="ECN 204">ECN 204</option>
<option value="FIN 300">FIN 300</option>
<option value="GMS 200">GMS 200</option>
<option value="ITM 100">ITM 100</option>
<option value="ITM 301">ITM 301</option>
<option value="ITM 305">ITM 305</option>
<option value="ITM 330">ITM 330</option>
<option value="ITM 350">ITM 350</option>
<option value="ITM 407">ITM 407</option>
<option value="ITM 410">ITM 410</option>
<option value="ITM 430">ITM 430</option>
<option value="ITM 500">ITM 500</option>
<option value="ITM 501">ITM 501</option>
<option value="ITM 505">ITM 505</option>
<option value="ITM 600">ITM 600</option>
<option value="ITM 700">ITM 700</option>
<option value="ITM 700">ITM 750</option>
<option value="ITM 820">ITM 820</option>
<option value="LAW 122">LAW 122</option>
<option value="SSH 105">SSH 105</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>
Choose a file to upload (Max 500MB): <input name="rye_file[]" type="file" id="multiple" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Why is my script always failing? Is there a more efficient way or cleaner way of implementing a file upload script?

If you come up with a better solution then my only requirement is that it allows the user to upload multiple files with a minimum file size of 500MB.

Comment: how does it fail? `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: var_dump gives the following: `array(1) { ["rye_file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "blue-theme.wbt.gz" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "application/x-gzip" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phppKL5HU" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(3969600) } } }`

Comment: that shows the file upload worked, whats the problem

Comment: The file upload failed, it doesn't transfer to the folder. That's the problem!

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?! This script is fustrating and my application requires the user to enter the directory to upload to. I need this script working!!!

Comment: NVM I found out that it was my directory permissions that was the cause of the problem

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header("Location: $url");` if it is not the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my directory permissions. I simply changed it to 777 using: 
`chmod -R 777 /path/to/site/uploads`

Comment: Please do not use 777 permisions for your web scripts and folders.
You should change directory owner to your web server user and make it writable only for it. 777 is a huge security problem for your site and neighbour.

Comment: @Ostin what user should I set it to in order for my file upload script to work?. I tried "owner" and "php" but nothing works. Thats why I just set the permission to 777

Comment: To determine user that runs webserver you can put `echo get_current_user();` in a test script and look at output. That would be script owner. Than in most cases 640 rights are enough. If you chmod files from php script do not forget leading 0 (0640, see php manual for info).

On different OS differend different system users run webserver. So you have to look at yours.